# Does the coefficient of friction (both static and kinetic) varies on prolonged application of friction forces?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, friction

Consider an example. Coefficient of Static Friction for a Pair of Materials for example Rubber tire and dry concrete road is 1.0 as per the data from my academic references. This coefficient of friction is due to the roughness / peaks on the surface of contact viewed in microscopic level. But I believe that peaks/roughness may get deformed on prolonged application of friction forces that is after long usage of wear and tear both the concrete road and rubber tire that coefficient may vary. Is my understanding right? If that coefficient will not vary what is the reason?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Ayyappan and welcome to the physics SE. I'm not sure why your question got closed as it seem clear to me. Yes, you are quite correct the friction can change due to _wear_. That is, the two surfaces abrade each ither and the surface roughness changes. For example this is exactly what happens with the bearings in a car engine during the [breaking in or running in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break-in_(mechanical_run-in)) process.

Comment: Thanks John Rennie. Got the answer.